# Why I didn't get xcode updates for xcode 9.0.1

Tags: xcode, app-store, updates

I'm using Xcode 8.3.3 and my os version is 10.12.6. when I look for updates in App Store it shows if there's any available updates but doesn't show any update for Xcode. if I searched for Xcode then it shows the button Install, not for Update. I'm wondering why is that. what happen if I Install ? Does it install as a new Xcode or update the existing version to 9.0.1 ? Hope your answer with this.

Comment: when you install 9.0.1 version Xcode then it will install new Xcode not update existing.

Comment: its every-time release new Xcode with new features so there is no update notification comes. you need to update by self from app store or anywhere else.

Answer (score 1):

Please upgrade to macOS High Sierra first